# use method value of Class1 in Class2 which extends Class1

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Stack with passing the sum value of `PairOfDice` class into `DiceRollerapp` Class, where, depending on the sum, a different message displays. No matter what, `sum` comes in as 0 in `DiceRollerapp`. Any help is appreciated greatly.

```
public class PairOfDice extends Die {

    private int sum;
    private int d1,d2;

    public PairOfDice() {
        super();
          }
public PairOfDice(int sum){
this.sum=sum;
}


    public int getValue1() {
        d1=super.getValue();
        return d1;
    }

    public int getValue2() {
        d2=super.getValue();
        return d2;
    }



    public int getSum(){
       sum=d1+d2;
    return sum;

    }

    public void setSum(int sum){
    this.sum=sum;
    } 

}
```

And:

```
public class DiceRollerapp extends PairOfDice{

private int total;

public DiceRollerapp() {
    super();
}
public DiceRollerapp(int sum) {
    super(sum);
}  



public String getMessage() {

   total=super.getSum();

    if (total == 7) {
        System.out.println("CRAPS!");
    } else if (total == 12) {
        System.out.println("BOX CARS!");
    } else if (total == 2) {
        System.out.println("SNAKE EYES!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return "";
}

}
```

Comment: This is a very strange use of the `extends` keyword.  When you say that one class extends another, what this really means is that all the objects of the first class are also objects of the second class.  In  your case, that would mean that a "pair of dice" is in fact a special type of "die"; and that a "dice roller app" is a special type of "pair of dice".  Neither of those ideas makes much sense to me.  I strongly suggest you consider writing this without using the words `extends`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that

```
public int getSum(){
  sum=d1+d2;
  return sum;
}
```

Always recalculates the sum based on `d1` and `d2`. That means you must set them before you call `getSum()`.

```
public String getMessage() {
  super.getValue1();    // <-- sets d1.
  super.getValue2();    // <-- sets d2
  total=super.getSum(); // <-- adds d1 and d2.
  if (total == 7) {
    System.out.println("CRAPS!");
  } else if (total == 12) {
    System.out.println("BOX CARS!");
  } else if (total == 2) {
    System.out.println("SNAKE EYES!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("");
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Elliot - corrected as advised. After few sleepless nights it does what i wanted.  Thanks